# Pandas: How to find index of value of one column whose cell value matches certain value

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe consists of the following table:

```
Time X Y
0100 5 9
0200 7 10
0300 11 12
0400 3 13
0500 4 14
```

My goal is to find the index of the value of Y which corresponds to a certain number (e.g.: 9) and return the corresponding X value from the table.

My idea previously was for a `for`-loop (as I have a number of Ys) to loop through and find all the values which match and then to create an empty array to store the values of X as such:

```
for i in (list of Ys):
    empty_storing_array.append(df[index_of_X].loc[df[Y] == i])
```

Problem is (if my newbie understanding of Pandas holds true), the values that `loc` gives is no number, but rather something else. How should I do it so that `empty_storing_array` then lists the numbers of X which corresponds to the values in array Y?

Comment: Is it always a 1-1 relationship?  If it is, just `set_index` to `Y` and use `loc`: `df.set_index('Y').loc[9, 'X']`

Comment: check .loc and bool slice

Comment: @user3483203 No, there is no 1-1 relationship, the sizes of both columns are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then ask for the index explicitly. This will return an array, so we slice the first item to get the integer:

```
df.loc[df['Y']==9, 'X'].index.values[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this :

```
list_Ys = [9,8,15] #example

new_df = df[df['Y'].isin(list_Ys)]['X']
```

the [`isin` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) tells whether each element in the DataFrame is contained in values.

if you want to convert your resulting dataframe to an array

```
new_df.values
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a way to retrieve which Y corresponds to a given X then keep both X and Y:

```
df.loc[df['Y'].isin(list_of_ys), ['Y', 'X']].values
```

Perhaps create a dictionary that puts all the Xs corresponding to a Y in a tuple and make the Y the keys.